# how to append multi indexed series to dataframe by for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have to get each CUS_ID's frequency of DAY, HOUR, and Type. In my code, I just get last CUS_ID's frequency. I don't know how to get all of it. I already tried pd.append( ignore_index= True), but it made my df disorganized.

This image is the compiled result. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odYWF.png)
There are 70 CUS_IDs, and 2449 is the last one.

## first_df has all raw data in this code.

```
DayFreq = first_df.groupby(['CUS_ID', 'DAY']).size()
HourFreq = first_df.groupby(['CUS_ID', 'TIME_HOUR']).size()
TypeFreq = first_df.groupby(['CUS_ID', 'ACT_NM']).size()

allCUS = first_df.groupby('CUS_ID').size() 
df_con = pd.DataFrame()
idx = 0

for idx in allCUS.index:
       df_con = pd.concat([DayFreq.loc[idx, :], HourFreq.loc[idx, :], TypeFreq.loc[idx, :]], axis = 0, join = 'outer') 
       idx = idx + 1
```

What I want to get is

```
CUS_ID DAY
2      FRI      925
        .
        .
        .
CUS_ID FRI      599
2449    .
        .
```

Like this!

What should I change in this cod to get this result?

Answer (score 0):

Why not just `sort_index`

```
pd.concat([DayFreq ,HourFreq ,TypeFreq],keys=[0,1,2]).sort_index(level=0)
```

Comment: I tried it, but it didn't print the data of DAY frequency first. I checked concatenated Series's index and I don't know why but DAY indexes are mixed between type indexes.